# How can I inject a string into a service factory?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to inject a string into a service factory, but am running into error `TS1206: Decorators are not valid here`.

I'm using the following code -

```
export let serviceFactory = (http: Http, @Inject('TEMPLATE') template: string) => {
    return new Service(http, template);
}
```

I use my factory like so -

```
export let serviceProvider = {
    provide: Service,
    useFactory: serviceFactory,
    deps: [Http]
};
```

How can I inject a string in a service factory?

Comment: How do you use serviceFactory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**app.module.ts**

```
export let serviceFactory = (http: Http, template: string) => {
  return new Service(http, template);
}

export let serviceProvider = {
  provide: Service,
  useFactory: serviceFactory,
  deps: [Http, [new Inject('TEMPLATE')]]
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule 
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'TEMPLATE', useValue: 'test' },
    serviceProvider,
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('TEMPLATE') template: string) {
      console.log(template);
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/K2Yy3Lz0BewDEsCda0QT?p=preview)**

Comment: Oh, cool! Had no idea you could use `Inject` like that. Thank you.