# Can't resolve all parameters for AddPassModal: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, testing

I am getting the error 
Can't resolve all parameters for AddPassModal: (?, ?).

I have tried some solution I have found on Stack overflow, but none seem to work.
This is for adding ng2-semantic-ui Component based
https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/modal

I can get the code to work fine. but he test fail when using the helper class.

here is the code in the ts file

```
export class PassesComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public modal:SuiModal<IAddPassModalContext, void, void>,
        public gu:GetUsersService, public formatDate:DateService, public policyService:PolicyService) {
  }
}

export class AddPassModal extends ComponentModalConfig<IAddPassModalContext, void, void> {
    constructor(title:string, question:string) {
        super(PassesComponent, { title, question });

        this.isClosable = false;
        this.transitionDuration = 200;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

this is the test file that is giving me a error
Can't resolve all parameters for AddPassModal: (?, ?).

```
interface IAddPassModalContext {
  title:string;
  question:string;
}


beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SuiModule       
      ],
      declarations: [ PassesComponent ,
        GuestComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [AddPassModal]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PassesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //mocAdd = new MocAddPassModal("test","test",ModalSize.Small);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

per some examples on GH, I have tried this.

```
interface IAddPassModalContext {
  title:string;
  question:string;
}


class MocAddPassModal extends ComponentModalConfig<IAddPassModalContext, void, void> {
    constructor(title:string = "", question:string = "") {
        super(PassesComponent, { title, question });
    }
}



describe('PassesComponent', () => {
  let component: PassesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PassesComponent>;
  let mocAdd: MocAddPassModal = new MocAddPassModal("test","test");


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SuiModule       
      ],
      declarations: [ PassesComponent ,
        GuestComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [AddPassModal, { provide: PassesComponent, useObject:mocAdd}]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PassesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    mocAdd = new MocAddPassModal("test","test");
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

   afterEach(() => {
    mocAdd = null;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

did not work.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your TestBed you are providing "AddPassModal", but the TestBed doesn't know how to construct it since its construction parameters are (string, string, ModalSize). None of which are provided or have injection tokens assigned. If you want to construct your AddPassModal via DI you might want to look into something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915497/3572942).

You probably want to just provide an instance of the AddPassModal service in your test:

```
providers: [ {provide: AddPassModal, useObject:new MocAddPassModal("test","test",ModalSize.Small)}]
```

Comment: Thank PeterB. changed my providers in  beforeEach to that. but I now get "can not find name 'provide': and. cannot find name 'useObject'. this work. ```providers: [{provide: AddPassModal,  useObject:new MocAddPassModal("test","test")}]``` but I get a " NullInjectorError: No provider for Modal!" error now.

Comment: Sorry, I lost a bracket there, edited the answer :)
OK so someone has a dependency to `Modal`, which isn't provided. Do you know where that might be requested? I sadly have no experience with ng2-semantic-ui

Comment: PeterB. thanks for your help in my .ts file the constrictor has ```constructor(public modal:SuiModal<IAddPassModalContext, void, void>,
    public gu:GetUsersService, public formatDate:DateService, public policyService:PolicyService) {
  }``` I added in my spec.ts file ```class MocSuiModal { 
    constructor(title:string = "", question:string = "") {

    }
}```  and changed providers to providers: [{ provide: SuiModal, useObject:new MocSuiModal("test","test")},
      { provide: AddPassModal, useObject:new MocAddPassModal("test","test")}] get Cannot read property 'context' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Big shout out to  @PeterB. He got me going down the right path.

so maybe this will help others. 
1st I added a couple Mocs

```
class MocAddPassModal extends ComponentModalConfig<IAddPassModalContext, void, void> {
    constructor(title:string = "", question:string = "") {
        super(PassesComponent, { title, question });
    }
}
class MocSuiModal{ 
    constructor(title:string = "", question:string = "") {

    }
}
```

2nd I added the providers like so

```
 providers: [{ provide: SuiModal, useObject:new MocSuiModal("test","test")},
      { provide: AddPassModal, useObject:new MocAddPassModal("test","test")}]
```

Than I was getting a context null error because componet.modal (modal) was null
To fix that I did

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PassesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.modal = new SuiModal<IAddPassModalContext, void, void>(new ModalControls(undefined,undefined),contextAddPass);
    fixture.detectChanges();
```

And it works.
now just need to get my test to 70% and everyone will be happy.